# Creating "belt area" using only certain longitudes but containing all latitudes in a non-rectangular CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to create a polygon in a vector layer containing **all** the "sunbelt" region (that's the area between 40°N to 40°S) in CRS "World_Mollweide" (`EPSG: 54009`) in order to use it as mask layer to clip it with a raster image that was created in CRS "World_Mollweide".
Any ideas how I can create such a shape without doing this manually and therefore omitting some areas on the lateral edges (see red circles in the screenshot) [image: Mollweide_World view with an incomplete polygon for the sunbelt area and red circles showing the missing gaps]

I am using QGIS 3.18.3

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**

You need to cover the whole layer extent, but lines are drawn between vertices always as straight lines on the map canvas (in the selected project CRS). Add additonal vertices to approximate the curved outer boundary of the World Mollweide projection. [See here for a similar problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392248/88814).

**Quick answer / generic solution (not software specific)**

First create a polygon covering the extent of the map canvas in a projection that is rectangular. Than densify this polygon (add additional vertices).

**Detailed answer for QGIS**

*Proceed the following, simple steps to get this resulting polygon hachured in red with extent form 40° N to 40° S:*

[image]

1. Create a new project and a new (temporary) layer with just one feauture in a projection with rectangular extent. I used `EPSG:3857` (web mercator) and created one point somewhere on the map. It's just an auxiliary layer as you need an input layer to create a new geometry (step 2).
2. Use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression`, set the layer created in step 1 as input, set output to `Polygon` and use this expression to create a rectangular polygon with the extreme points of the WebMercator projection (the maximum/minimum extent, covering the whole layer extent). If you want only from 40° N to 40° S, replace  the values of `+/-85.051129` with `+/-40`:

```
transform (
    make_polygon (
        make_line (
            make_point ( -180.000000, -85.051129),
            make_point ( 180.000000, -85.051129),
            make_point ( 180.000000, 85.051129),
            make_point ( -180.000000, 85.051129)
    )),
    'EPSG:4326' ,
    'EPSG:3857' 
)
```

3. Use [`Menu Processing / Toolbox / Densify by interval`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#densify-by-interval). Set the layer from step 2 as input and select a value for `Interval between vertices to add` of e.g. 1000 [meters].

You're done! Project your map to `World_Mollweide` by setting the project CRS at the very bottom right in your QGIS window (**not the layer CRS**) to `EPSG:54009`. The densified polygon is still in `WorldMercator/EPSG:3857`, but the densified vertices smoothly reproject on the fly to the projection of the map canvas (project CRS).

If you want, you can [re-project](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/crs.html) the densified layer to `EPSG:54009` by either `right-clinging layer / Export / Save Features As...` or using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Reproject layer` and selecting `EPSG:54009`.

*Same procedure, but for the whole extent of `EPSG:3857`*
[image]