# Creating polygon covering the whole layer extent using QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, polygon, extents, expression

Using QGIS expressions, it's easy to create a polygon with the extent (bounding box) covering all geometries of a layer using `layer_property(@layer,'extent')`.

However, how do I get a polygon covering the whole **layer extent**, not only the extent of the geometry?

See the screenshot: the expression generates the blue polygon. However, I look for an expression generating a polygon symbolized here with the pink frame:

[image]

Comment: I do not really understand the purpose of this action?

Comment: See here why:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402125/88814 - to be able to get the output of `layer_property('OpenStreetMap','extent')` without need of loading another layer (OpenStreetMap).

Comment: So, layer-extent would be equal to CRS-extent?

Comment: Yes, I guess so

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a [custom function](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#function-editor) to get crs extent.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def crs_extent(layer_name, feature, parent):
    layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)
    
    if layers:
        bounds = layers[0].crs().bounds()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Layer {layer_name} could not found")
        
    return QgsGeometry.fromRect(bounds)
```

---

Result for `crs_extent(@layer_name)`:

[image]

Result for `crs_extent('OSM')`: (No empty space at the top/bottom)

[image]

**Note:** `Layer`'s CRS is WGS84 (EPSG:4326). If you use projected CRS for `Layer`, you may not get an expected result. For example, UTM's unit is meter, but `crs().bounds()` returns bounds in degree.

Comment: Avoiding a thank you message, still a warm "welcome back" message - we missed you here !

Comment: Nice, indeed! And `transform (crs_extent( 'layer_name'), 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857')` does the job to get it to another projection.

Comment: YOU are an expert in expression, not me. :)