# Creating grid in QGIS 3.18.3

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, point, vector-grid, polygon-creation

How do I draw a grid of n by n on the shapefile of a city with a CRS of EPSG:4326?

I have tried creating gird in ESPG:32735

[image: Image with EPSG:32735]

I have created a grid using this.

> Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Grid

But when I try to export it as EPSG:4326, this grid gets stretched, and I can't use it in python.

Multiple tries that I did

> SAGA -> Vector general -> Create polygons graticule 
> MMQGIS -> Create -> Create Grid Layer

[image: Image with EPSG:4326]

**Python result**

[image: python stretched grdi]

```
temp_shapefile = gpd.read_file('../temp/tempgrid.shp') <br>
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15)) <br>
temp_shapefile.boundary.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.4, color="black") <br>
df_Selected.plot(ax=ax, markersize = 15,color = "black", legend=True)
```

Comment: don't use 4326 for analysis - stick with the local projection

Comment: If I stick to the system 32735, I can't draw that in Python

Comment: why not? any reasonable mapping library should handle that projection

Answer (score 2):

The grid gets distorted when you change the projection of the map ([see here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392248/88814)). Create the grid in the projection you want to use for the output, thus in your case in EPSG:4326 (WGS84). As units in this projection are in degrees, however, you should calculate an appropriate value for the grid distance.

See @Ian Turton's comment, however: don't use 4326 for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Create your grid in EPSG:3857 (aka Web Mercator), then reproject to WGS84 and save.

Comment: Web Mercator doesn't support accurate distance measurement. That makes it inappropriate for grid generation.